# Issues with variable length lists and Validation Errors in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I am currently working on a form using asp.net-mvc 4 that submits an object with a variable number of sub-objects stored in an IList.

I'm running in to an issue with validation messages being attached to the incorrect object in the IList if an error is returned.  If the first object in the list is deleted and the second object (that then becomes the first) has errors in it, the incorrect object does not get the correct validation result on page reload.  The object in the list that had an index of 3 is given an index of 2 when the error is returned, which also changes the previous (possibly correct) selections at the same time.

**Is there any way to change which objects in a list the previous validation errors get attached to?**

Edit: The validation messages are in the correct location because the "ValidationIndex" is working, the highlighting is where I'm having the issue.

I've tried adding in a "ValidationIndex" to the objects in the list to send the validation errors to the correct place.  This has worked for the error message but the incorrect object is still having its fields highlighted and changed.

Removing the ability to delete anything except the last object would obviously be one way to solve this issue, but I'm really hoping to find a way to keep the functionality.  I'd also like to avoid having to make an http request every time a new box is added if at all possible.

Here is an imgur album showing the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRMfD.jpg

Here is an example of the code I'm using:

The container class:

```
public class TestProduct : Product
{
    public IList<TestItem> TItems { get; set; }

    public TestProduct()
    {
        TItems = new List<TestItem>();
    }
}
```

The class in the list:

```
public class TestItem : IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name = "Select 1")]
    public string select1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select 2")]
    public string select2 { get; set; }

    // Added to try and Identify where the validation errors need to go
    public int ValidationIndex { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (select1 == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Required", new string[] { "select1" });
        }

        if (select2 == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Required", new string[] { "select2" });
        }

        if (select1 == select2)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The options cannot be the same", new string[] { "select2", "select1" });
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model TestProduct

@{
    List<SelectListItem> selectOptions = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Choose...", Value = "" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Value = "o1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 2", Value = "o2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 3", Value = "o3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 4", Value = "o4" }
    };
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var itemContainer = $('#items');
        var i = $('#items .item-option').length;

        $('#addItem').on("click", function (e) {
            if ($('#items .item-option').length <= 15) {
                var newField = '<fieldset class="item-option"> ' +
                        '<legend>Item ' + (i + 1) + '</legend>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="TItems.Index" value="' + i + '" /> ' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="TItems[' + i + '].ValidationIndex" value="' + i + '" /> ' +
                        '<div class="line"> ' +
                            '<div> ' +
                                '<div class="label"><label for="select1-' + i + '">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TItems[0].select1)</label></div> ' +
                                '<div> ' +
                                    '<select id="select1-' + i + '" name="TItems[' + i + '].select1"> ' +
                                        @foreach (SelectListItem so in selectOptions)
                                        {
                                            <text>
                                                '<option value="@so.Value">@so.Text</option> ' +
                                            </text>
                                        }
                                    '</select> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                            '</div> ' +
                            '<div> ' +
                                '<div class="label"><label for="select2-' + i + '">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TItems[0].select2)</label></div> ' +
                                '<div>' +
                                    '<select id="select2-' + i + '" name="TItems[' + i + '].select2"> ' +
                                        @foreach (SelectListItem so2 in selectOptions)
                                        {
                                            <text>
                                                '<option value="@so2.Value">@so2.Text</option> ' +
                                            </text>
                                        }
                                    '</select> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                            '</div> ' +
                        '</div> ' +    
                        '<div class="pos-rb"><button class="remItem smalltext">Remove</button></div> ' +
                    '</fieldset>';
                itemContainer.append(newField);
                $('.remItem:hidden').show();
                i++;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#items').on("click", '.remItem', function (e) {
            var n = $('#items .item-option').length;
            if (n >= 2) {
                $(this).closest('.item-option').remove();
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                $('.remItem').hide();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>

<h3>Test Product</h3>
<div class="indented">
    <div id="items" class="items question">
        @if (Model.TItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.TItems.Count; i++)
            {
                int validationIndex = Model.TItems[i].ValidationIndex;
                <text>
                    <fieldset class="item-option">
                        <legend>Item @(i + 1)</legend>
                        <input type="hidden" name="TItems.Index" value="@i" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="TItems[@i].ValidationIndex" value="@i" />
                        <div class="line">
                            <div>
                                <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TItems[i].select1)</div>
                                <div>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TItems[i].select1, new SelectList(selectOptions, "Value", "Text", Model.TItems[i].select1))<br />
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TItems[validationIndex].select1)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TItems[i].select2)</div>
                                <div>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TItems[i].select2, new SelectList(selectOptions, "Value", "Text", Model.TItems[i].select2))<br />
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TItems[validationIndex].select2)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="pos-rb">
                            <button class="remItem smalltext" @if (Model.TItems.Count == 1) { <text> style="display: none;" </text> }>Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </text>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
                <fieldset class="item-option">
                    <legend>Item 1</legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="TItems.Index" value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="TItems[0].ValidationIndex" value="0" />
                    <div class="line">
                        <div>
                            <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TItems[0].select1)</div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TItems[0].select1, new SelectList(selectOptions, "Value", "Text"))
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TItems[0].select2)</div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TItems[0].select2, new SelectList(selectOptions, "Value", "Text"))
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pos-rb"><button class="remItem smalltext" style="display: none;">Remove</button></div>
                </fieldset>
            </text>
        }
    </div>
    <button id="addItem" class="smalltext" style="margin-left: 2em;">Add Another Item</button>
    <br />
    <div style="margin: 1em;"><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I figured out a rather messy work around using JavaScript.  Every time an item is removed it goes through and replaces all the names, ids, and for fields for all the inputs and their labels in the form.  It's not exactly elegant, but it's working so far...

Here's the new remove item event handler:

```
$('#items').on("click", ".remItem", function (e) {
    var n = $("#items .item-option").length;
    if (n >= 2) {
        $(this).closest(".item-option").remove();
    }
    if (n == 2) {
        $(".remItem").hide();
    }
    $("#items").find(".item-option").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find(".item-index").val(index);
        $(this).find("select, input, textarea").each(function () {
            var name1 = $(this).attr('name');
            if (name1 != null) {
                var name2 = name1.replace(/TItems\[\d+\]/, "TItems[" + index + "]");
                $(this).attr("name", name2);
            }
            var id1 = $(this).attr("id");
            if (id1 != null) {
                var id2 = id1.replace(/_\d+__/, "_" + index + "__");
                $(this).attr("id", id2);
            }
        });
        $(this).find("label").each(function () {
            var for1 = $(this).attr("for");
            if (for1 != null) {
                var for2 = for1.replace(/_\d+__/, "_" + index + "__");
                $(this).attr("for", for2);
            }
        });
        $(this).find("legend").html("Item " + (index+1));
    });
    i--;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You have `DropDownListFor(model => model.TItems[i].select1, ..)` and `ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TItems[validationIndex].select1)`. Are the values of `i` and `validationIndex` the same?

Comment: No, the ValidationIndex value contains the value of the previous TItems.Index I believe.  In the example I gave, the ValidationIndex for the first item is 2 after submission and i is 1.

Comment: Then that why the validation error does not match. Try using `model => model.TItems[i].select1` But I think you have other problems also - such as if there a 4 rows and the user deletes the 2nd, then adds an new one - your indexer `TItems.Index` will have values 0,2,3,3 - which wont bind correctly. Consider basing the indexer for new (dynamically added) rows on a unique value such as `var i = (new Date()).getTime();`

Comment: I'm probably explaining the issue incorrectly here.  If I use that, then both the message and the highlighting go to the wrong item.  The validation index has actually gotten me half way to what I need, the highlighting needs to be where the error message currently is.  Regarding the indexing issue, the variable i in the javascript never goes down, so removing rows does not create duplicate indexes.

Comment: I went and checked to make sure, this is the result of having 4 rows, deleting the second, then adding a 5th.  The indexes are all unique. http://imgur.com/sLDw8TH

Comment: If the html looks like `<input name="TItems[0].select1" ...>
<span data-valmsg-for="TItems[0].select1" ...></span>` then the messages should match (the `data-valmsg-for` specifies the matching input name element). If I get a chance I have a closer look at your code tomorrow, but not sure how the indexers could be unique since you base the new indexer on `var i = $('#items .item-option').length;` (maybe I missed something else in your code)

Comment: It's because the indexer variable is set to the number of items on document ready, but is never set to the length again until the page reloads.  It increments every time a value is added, but is never decremented.  As far as I can tell, the issue with the highlighting is happening because the error WAS for object 2, but on page reload object 2 has become object 1.  The ValidationIndex allows me to display the error message for object 2 attached to object 1 on page reload.  Thanks for taking the time to try and help me out. :)